# One-letter word at the end of line of text

Tags: word-order

In English language, is a **one-letter word** (such as *I* or *a*) allowed to be at the **end of line**?  (This question is about a single-letter word within a sentence, placed just before a linebreak.)

For example, is this allowed?

> It was a sunny day yesterday, so I
>   took a sunbath.

In the example, *I* is at the end of a line of text, just before a linebreak.

Comment: Are you asking if a sentence may end with, say, an 'I'?

Comment: Yes, I am asking exactly that.

Comment: At the end of a line, or the end of a sentence?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but is there a language where this is not the case?

Comment: It's bad form to have a single letter from a hyphenated word standing a- lone at the end of a line.

Comment: @AndrewLeach As I state in the question, "at the end of line".

Comment: Single letters exist apart from hyphens. Some are words (Who were chosen? ... You and I.) Some are not (In French, I only got a D.)

Comment: I edited the question - I put there an example.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: @Mitch Example sentence: "I like apples", where the letter 'I' will be at the end of line.

Comment: Here's a related discussion from the typography stack exchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line

Comment: In the sentence "I like apples." the 'I' is at the beginning. What about at the -end- as you asked for? I'm not asking about the beginning, am I?

Comment: This question is still unclear. Is this about hyphenation or wrapping words from one line to the next? You need to give an explicit example of what you think might be a problem.

Comment: I edited the title and the question to be more clear.

Comment: This is a typography question, not an English question. I understand [graphicdesign.se] welcomes such questions.

Comment: The comments to this question are misleading - Peter 'confirms' that the question is about the end of a sentence, but the question/later comments 'confirms' that it is the end of a line that is being asked about :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. There is nothing to prevent a single-letter word like *I* or *a* from being on its own at the end of a line. Sometimes a text just happens to fall that way.

However, it's bad form in English to split a word in such a way that a single letter ends the line a- lone, with a hyphen.

The Wikipedia article on [syllabification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification) provides a clue:

> For example, it is not possible to syllabify "learning" as *lear-ning* according to the correct syllabification of the living language. Seeing only *lear-* at the end of a line might mislead the reader into pronouncing the word incorrectly, as the digraph *ea* can hold many different values. The history of English orthography accounts for such phenomena.

Leaving just a single letter on the end of a line, like *alone* above, slows down the reading more than forcing the whole word on to the next line (perhaps by widening the space between words if the text is fully justified).

---

I don't know if my contrived text will work on your system, so here's what it should look like:

[image: Text example]

Comment: So you say, that a **single letter** can be at the end of line but a **single letter with hyphen** cannot?

Comment: There are no **rules** as such in English typography, but yes. If the single letter is a word on its own, that's fine. If the single letter is part of another word, it's not fine. [There are rules in grammar, of course.]

Comment: No. He's saying that a **single-letter word** (i.e. a word that consists of a single letter, e.g. *a*, *I*) can be at the end of a line. But a **word that is split over two lines** (using a hypen) should not be split so as to leave a single letter at the end of the first line - nor in fact to leave a single letter at the beginning of the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one-letter word **is allowed** to be at the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

If the letter is a word, as @EdwinAshworth points out, there is no problem whatsoever. People are used to reading "I" and "A" and, possibly "O", as words and not typos. If the letter represents a letter, though, you might momentarily confuse a reader because they aren't used to seeing it stand alone. For instance, if, at the end of a line of a piece of fiction you were to encounter an R by itself,  it might look unattractive, owing to the starkness of it being the last symbol of the line. This could be rectified by capitalizing it, as I have done, or putting it in quotes to clarify that it isn't a typo. It isn't wrong, though, as there is no way to correct for it.

Edit: After google searching "single letters at the end of a line", a pretty generic search, I found quite a few discussions on this topic on typography and programming forums.

From an Adobe forum:

> hi helpers, i've been working on a text the client of which wants single-letter words NOT to be at the ends of lines. does ID have any tool to prevent these words from being at the ends of lines? i think that it could be done by inserting non-breaking space after these words, but how to do that without searching them and inserting the space after each manualy (too time consuming...)?

From a LaTex forum:

> Hi,
>   is there a way to forbid TeX break lines right after "a" or "of"? 
>   Of course, I do put "~" after such words often, but I also often 
>   forget to do so. 
>   Maybe there is a dictionary of words that are forbidden to 
>   appear at the end of a line?

From an apache forum:

> In many languages the formal way of presenting text (not many know about this -
>   because of lack of such functionality in *other* word processors) is that there
>   cannot be any "single letter" words at the end of a line (Polish is one of the
>   examples).

These all suggest stylistic preferences, and I would say these discussions are analogous to the way typesetters avoid [widows and orphans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans). In over ten years of writing for English newspapers, I've never been prompted to avoid ending lines with a single letter word. Apparently, though, it is very common to avoid it in certain Eastern European language typographies: Polish, Slavak, and Czech, for example.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to force a single letter like your R to appear at the start of the next line rather than the end of a line.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I was trying to force it to the end of the line, which is why the sentence got so wordy.

Comment: Yes (although it doesn't look like that on my system). What I meant was there ***are*** ways of correcting for a single letter on the end of a line if you want to do that -- with expanded word- or letter-spacing, or in HTML with a non-breaking space after it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think you can even do a non-breaking space in *MS Word*.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, the standard shortcut key to insert a non-breaking space in _MS Word_ is `CTRL + SHIFT + SPACE`.

Comment: @PeterSivák: What, if you don't mind, is your first language, and is this a common typographical practice in it?

Comment: @tylerharms His website (linked from his profile page) says "Language Skills: Slovak (mother tongue), Speaking – native,  Writing – native; English, Speaking – intermediate,  Writing – advanced; German, Speaking – basic, Writing – basic."

Comment: @TrevorD Lol, with German it is still worse and worse :)